# Throwing error when Json Configuration is missing or not loaded correctly (Core IOptions Configuration Injection)

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, asp.net-core

I've was playing with Asp.Net Core & JSON IOptions configuration using [this MSDN article for instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects). For a while, I couldn't get my configuration section loading.  It was coming through to the controller with properties as NULL.

I fixed the issue but it was made harder without any run time errors saying "section not found" or similar messages.  Is there a way to get .Net to throw an error if the configuration section is missing or doesn't load properly?

Comment: Very interesting question, but can you add some example code that demonstrates your problem?